# Can I stop an event handler while it's executing?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to stop the execution of a previous event when the event is called again?

To clarify, I have a button `<button onclick='load()'>load</button>` that calls a load() function which gets an array, processes each element and displays it in a list `<ul id='main'></ul>`

```
function load(event) {
            $("#main").empty();               //empty old elements
            $.get("load.php", '', function (data) {
                var arr = JSON.parse(data);
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
                    process(arr[I]);          //process and append to #main
                }
            });
        }
```

Problem is, that if I click the button again while its still putting the elements into the array, I get the new list plus the rest of the old list.

Is there a way to stop the first event while its still executing but still execute the second event?

Comment: Yes, based on the `EventObject.eventPhase`.

Comment: @PHPglue can you explain alittle more?

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you can stop the event by setting a flag and checking it, but a better approach would simply be to assign the new value directly. If your code works it means `JSON.parse` is returning an array already.

That means

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    function load(event) {
        $("#main").empty();
        $.get("load.php", '', function (data) {
            process = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#main").whateverMethodFillsTheElement(process);
        });
}());
```

Also, when writing asynchronous JavaScript code that makes HTTP requests, promises are preferred to callbacks. Since `$.get` returns a Promise you can write

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    function load(event) {
        $("#main").empty();
        $.get("load.php")
            .then(function (data) {
                var items = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#main").whateverMethodFillsTheElement(items);
            });
    }
}());
```

As discussed in comments, the aim is to use each item in another request which provides the actual value to add to 'main'. So loading data triggers an asynchronous call for each loaded item.

To accommodate this, we need to determine a *key* field that we can use to track each item so we do not append existing items to the list. We will call this field `id` for the sake of exposition.

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    var allItems = [];

    function load(event) {
        $("#main").empty();
        $.get("load.php")
            .then(function (data) {
              return JSON.parse(data);
            })
            .then(function (items) {
              items.forEach(item => {
                processItem(item)
                  .then(function (processed) {
                    var existingItem = allItems.filter(i => i.id === item.id)[0];
                    if(existingItem) {
                      var existingIndex = allItems.indexOf(existingItem);
                      allItems[existingIndex] = processed;
                    } 
                    else {
                      allItems.push(processed);
                    }
                  });
              });
          });
    }
}());
```

Comment: I'm using each item in another request which gives me the value to add to 'main', and that takes time so I want to add each item as it comes

Comment: Then you will need a flag. What do you want to have happen when a user requests more data while data is loading?

Comment: The old data to stop loading

Comment: OK, that is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
var xhr;
function load(ev){
  if(ev.eventPhase === 2){
    if(xhr)xhr.abort();
    $('#main').empty(); 
    xhr = $.get('load.php', function(data){
      var a = JSON.parse(data);
      for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
        process(a[i]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get the new event to override the old event, not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but...

```
var req = $.ajax({
        $("#main").addEventListener("click",()=>{req.abort()})
        ...
        ...
        $("#main").removeEventListener("click",()=>{req.abort()})
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like it's not possible to stop an Ajax success function after it began executing or to stop a past event without aborting the current one.
But the following solution worked for me so I figured I'll post it here:

```
var num = 0;
function load() {
    var curNum = ++num;
    $("#main").empty();               
    $.get("load.php", '', function (data) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(data);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            process(arr[i], curNum); 
        }
    });
}
function process(item, curNum) {
    if(curNum === num) {  //don't process if a new request has been made
        //get 'data' based on 'item'...
        if(curNum === num) {  //check again in case a new request was made in the meantime
            $("#main").append(data);
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate everyone's help.